# unwanted <br> and <p> tags in text editor

Tags: tinymce, html-editor

I'm very surprised that an answer to this isn't easy to find.  I've been searching for a solution to this problem for some time now.  Google has a few sketchy answers, but they're old.  My question is this:

When I'm adding content to a page, I prefer to use the "text" tab (not the "visual" one), and I often paste in a large amount of HTML.  Each time I do so, and update (save) the page, when I come back, the code has been changed.  br tags are added, things are changed to unwanted paragraph tags, etc.

I found this on codex:
In formatting.php Change the line

```
function wpautop($pee, $br = 1)
```

to
    function wpautop($pee, $br = 0)

...but I'm opposed to changing the core files (as we all are!).

I've seen ways to turn off TinyMCE, but those articles are over 8 years old, and aren't relevant any longer.

So is there any way I can put in code into the text editor, and have it stay strictly the way I put it in?  I'm open to all solutions - I won't be offended if a plugin recommendation is made.

Comment: PLEASE please, if you think this question doesn't fit this site, just let me know why.  Please don't downvote it without at least some clarity.  I did my best to make a clear question and I'd really appreciate constructive criticism (if there is any issue that you find).

Comment: Have you tried removing the wpautop filter from the_content, like `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` ?

Comment: @czerspalace Thanks for your comment; is that possible to do without editing the core files?

Comment: [Mark](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/59862/mark), yes, you can add that line to the functions.php file in your theme directory

Comment: Have you managed to get this working in the end? I'm stuck on the same problem 3 years later.

Comment: @zool Hmm, this is a while back, but I think I used a [raw] tag, with a plugin?